# Cannot use INT variable in MySQL LEFT function

Tags: mysql, substring, mysql-workbench

I have been perplexed by the fact that MySQL Workbench 6.2 reports a syntax error in stored routines using the `LEFT` string function with INT variables:

```
declare lclPos int; 
declare lclPart varchar(100);  
...
set lclPart = LEFT(lclTemp, lclPos - 1);
```

The error reads

> Syntax error: 'lclPos' (identifier) is not valid input as this point.

However, if I change the code to the equivalent

```
set lclPart = SUBSTRING(lclTemp, 1, lclPos - 1);
```

no error is reported. And a constant integer (but no local variable) works when using `LEFT`.

These routines using the `LEFT` function were coded a long time ago and I have not experienced any problem with this code. Oddly, the existing routines continue to work on the server despite the fact that syntax errors are reported. This leaves me thinking that this could be due to a bug in MySQL Workbench 6.2. The server runs MySQL 5.5.

Has anybody any idea about what's happening here?

Answer (score 1):

```
set lclPart =  (select LEFT(lclTemp, lclPos - 1));
```

you will have no errors

Comment: Good point. You need to put parentheses around the `select` statement. However, despite this change the problem persists: the syntax error is identical. `SUBSTRING` works though: `set lclPart = (select substring(lclTemp, 1, lclPos - 1));`